# In R, How to create another variable whose values are based on FAVECTOR

Tags: r, categories

The variable EVENT is the time in minute when the even occurs.

For example, `EVENT[1] = 15, EVENT[100]= 3400`.

Now I want to creataan new variable, TIME.

If EVEN[n] is in the interval `(34*(i-1)+1, 34*i], then TIME[n] = i`.

How to create the new variable TIME?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ..what is `i`, and what should `TIME[n]` be otherwise?

Comment: ...and what does it have to do with "FAVECTOR" - what is that?

Comment: Although there is no official naming convention for R, you should avoid ALLCAPS, except perhaps for constants.

Comment: Also, are `EVEN` and `EVENT` the same variable with a typo or two different variables?

Comment: This question will be a lot easier to answer if you give us the code that you have so far, and have a little think about what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: probably something along the lines of `TIME <- as.numeric(cut(EVENT,breaks=seq(0,(max(EVENT/34)+1)*34,by=34)))`

Comment: and by the way ... http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000

Comment: @Tommy sorry to make you confused, Matthew Lundberg gave the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each n > 1, we have that TIME[n] = EVENT[n] %/% 34 (integer division).

Thus, the code to produce TIME is:

```
TIME <- EVENT %/% 34
```